# Running a Classic ASP Application on 32-Bit Windows Seven With IIS 7.5

Tags: sql-server, windows-7, iis-7, asp-classic, database-connection

I recently upgraded my computer from XP to Windows Seven. I was using IIS 6.0 but I am now on IIS 7.5. When I was on my XP machine I was able to get my **Classic ASP** pages running and viewable. I am working being ableto run a Classic ASP page from my local drive. I am using SQL Server 2005. I set up IIS 7.5 with an application pool with .NET Framework Version 2.0. When I try to run the page I get the error: "**Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '80004005' [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified**". My code looks like this:

```
randomConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=server\instance;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=MyFakeUserID;Password=MyFakePassword;"
Set someRS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
mySQLStatement = "SELECT DISTINCT CarInfo.CarMake, CarInfo.CarColor FROM CarInfo"
someRS.Open mySQLStatement, randomConnection
```

The code errors out on the last line. My code has a lot more that it does after all this. All of the code worked fine with IIS 6.0. The only changes are I switched to Windows Seven 32-bit and IIS 7.5. Is there something special that needs down since I have IIS 7.5? I have created test ASP pages in the root directory without any database logic and the page rendered just fine.

Comment: I downloaded the most recent MDAC. Is there another that I could be missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connection string is using the wrong provider - **SQLOLEDB** is a data provider for [SQL Server 2000 or SQL Server 7](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server). You should be using **SQLNCLI** (or **SQLNCLI10**) according to [SQL Server 2005 connection strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2005#p111).

Try this...

`Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=server\instance;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=MyFakeUserID;Password=MyFakePassword;`

You are also trying to open the connection using `mySQLStatement` as the connection string. You need to revisit the documentation on [how to connect](http://www.w3schools.com/ado/met_conn_open.asp) and [request data](http://support.discountasp.net/KB/a356/how-to-query-sql-database-with-asp-using-dsn-less-connection.aspx) from ADODB.

Comment: I tried put in SQLNCLI and restarted IIS. It had the same result. I tried it with SQLNCLI10 and had the same result.

Comment: Try changing the IIS application pool advanced settings to enable 32bit apps to true.

Comment: I've tried going into the App Pool. I right-clicked and went to advance settings and the option isn't there. I think its not there since Im on a 32 bit platform already.

Comment: Can you verify there is a SQL Instance running for the assigned "Data Source"?

Comment: I do not know how to do that. (Still a noob at database connections)

Comment: Use [SSMS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961) to connect to the database instance using the user/password and Data Source you describe.

Comment: Open up Windows Services (type services.msc into start/the run dialog) and look for a service named 'SQL Server (Instance)' or check whether you can connect to server\instance in Management Studio. Infact, I'd drop the 'server' part and use .\Instance in your connection string if it's on the same machine.

Comment: The database lives on another server outside of my machine

Comment: I have SQL Server 2005 installed on my machine and I am able to connect and authenticate through the server\instance values

Comment: Does the database catalog exist (*Initial Catalog*)?

Comment: Yeah it's there, I also tried putting in a database that I knew didn't exist and it gave me a different error.

Comment: CORRECTION: I put in a database I knew doesn't exist and it was the same error. Tried a database I knew exists and same error.

Comment: Try adding "Connect Timeout=15;Network Library=dbmssocn;" to your connection string.

Comment: Your code is invalid - see updated answer. You cannot open a connection with the SQL statement as a parameter. Please review sample link and documentation on how to open the connection.

Comment: Oops I forgot its not ADODB.Connection Im using ADODB.RecordSet. When I change it to that the page broke on an include page. It's now blowing up on a line that says "Set randomSoapClient = Server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient")" Which is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way you connect to the server does it work or give you a different error? I get different errors between using your version above and the version we use (the error I get with the below is because I don't have an instance called server\instance):

```
Set someRS = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
someRS.ActiveConnection = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=server\instance;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=MyFakeUserID;Password=MyFakePassword;"
someRS.CommandText = "SELECT DISTINCT CarInfo.CarMake, CarInfo.CarColor FROM CarInfo" 
someRS.Prepared = true

Set someRSResults = someRS.Execute
```

Also, we use SQLOLEDB which has worked with SQL Server 2000, 2005 and 2008. Maybe we need to update it to the later one, but it should work.

Comment: It gets me through that line but errors on someRS.EOF saying its not supported. ( a line further down)

Comment: I've updated my code above, try using someRSResults to access your data (e.g. someRSResults.EOF etc).

Comment: What does it need initialized to? It breaks at that line saying someRSResults is undefined.

Comment: Did you add the Set someRSResults = someRS.Execute line from my edit above?

Comment: Hmm.. have you got option explicit enabled? Are you able to post all of your code (stripping out anything sensitive)?